# An attempt was made to call the method but it does not exist

Tags: spring

An attempt was made to call the method `org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isCandidateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z` but it does not exist. Its class, `org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils`, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of `org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils`

Help me!

Comment: spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar have AnnotationUtils class but this class doesn't nave  isCandidateClass. Please find appropriate jar.

Comment: @MohdYasin I see

Answer (score 0):

Please check maven dependency::tree, it must be some jar package(spring core with difference version) conflict.